# window.history.back() takes two clicks to go back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

Here is my primary Route (route 1):

```
http://myportal.fakedomain.com:8080/src/#/dashboard
```

Now from this route, I'm going to a static route(using a button and sending query params) (route 2)

```
http://myportal.fakedomain.com:8080/src/#/my-table?group=Decision%20Gate&start_date=2020-06-01&end_date=2020-08-31
```

On this route page, I get a back button which should take me to the (route 1). But when i'm clicking on the back button the url got changed (following route) and it takes another click to go to the route 1. You see the date query param changes but the page not get refreshed.

```
http://myportal.fakedomain.com:8080/src/#/my-table?group=Decision%20Gate&start_date=Mon%20Jun%2001%202020%2000:00:00%20GMT%2B0600%20(Bangladesh%20Standard%20Time)&end_date=Mon%20Aug%2031%202020%2000:00:00%20GMT%2B0600%20(Bangladesh%20Standard%20Time)
```

Here is the view code

```
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary bck-btn margin-0" ng-click="vm.backToMM()">
      <md-icon md-font-icon="icon-arrow-back" class="font-size-fixed-14"></md-icon>
      <span class="v-mid margin-right-0"> Back </span>
</md-button>
```

Here is back function

```
vm.backToMM = function(){
    window.history.back();
}
```

Can anyone help me, how can I avoid clicking two times to go to the back. Here you don't need to bother about vm. I add "this" parent controller to this vm variable.

Comment: According to the History API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API, I suppose you can use window.history.go(-2).

Comment: can't use that because i also use this back button from another navigation where it's working well. Adding "window.history.go(-2)" won't work there.

Comment: Not sure if it has anything to do with MVC but that is what I'm using.  .Net Framework 4.7 and MVC 5.  Anyway, I have to call `window.history.back()` twice and then it works.

Comment: ...or maybe it has something to do with the fact that I just finished an ajax call from javascript, no idea.